# Perl Regex prevent repeated characters for password policy

Tags: php, regex, perl

I'm using a passwordpolicy library from this site written in PHP http://craig-russell.co.uk/password-policy/index.html
It uses perl regex for most of its rules. 
I have been trying to add a new rule to make it not accept 3 repeated characters.
I've tried severals regex that has been posted and asked about here and this is the one I've recently tried out
    `[\w((.)\1{3,}]`
But it just don't seem to work

It matches aaaa but if you write aaab it still matches it. Seems like it trying to match the string as a whole
This is the array where the regex goes:

`$this->rules['max_allowedsame_chars'] = array(`
            `'value' => false,`
            `'type'  => 'integer',`
           `'test'  => 'return preg_match_all("/[\w ((.)\1{3,})/",$p,$x)<=$v;',`
            `'error' => 'Password cant contain no more than #VALUE# of the same characters');`

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use square brackets, they mean character class and most metacharacters lose their meaning in them. Try:

```
preg_match_all("/(.)\1{2,}/",$p,$x)
```

This will match if you have 3 repeated characters or more, but fail if there's less.

The first character is caught in the first capture group and the next two (or more) are matched by `\1{2,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', $p)
```