# Regex-check if whole of string is a single repeating character - by PHP

Tags: php, regex, passwords

I want to **prevent users to just use repeated one letter or any others characters** in whole string of username or password fields for registering new user by PHP.
I search in google and regex wiki and stackoverflow and regex101 but I couldn't find my answer.

minimum of length for username and password characters is 8.

> Rules:
>
> **in username or password fields for registering new user**
>   11111111,111111111111,22222222,222222222222,...,aaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbb,...,zzzzzzzz,...@@@@@@@@,********
>   ,&&&&&&&&... should be invalid 
>   but 
>   11111113,22222221,...,aaaaaaab,baaaaaaa,...,zzzczzzz,...@@@1@@@@,2*******
>   ,&&&&&n&&... should be valid.

**I found this patterns but doesnt work and has warning:**

```
 pattern1:    ^(?!.*(.)\1).{*}$
 pattern2:    ^(.)\1{1,}$
```

> warning is this:
>
> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:...\test.php on line 70

please help me to resolve that.

this posts was not my answer and doesnt work:

[match the same unknown character multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460397/match-the-same-unknown-character-multiple-times)

[Perl Regex prevent repeated characters for password policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175430/perl-regex-prevent-repeated-characters-for-password-policy)

UPDATE:

Thanks panter.it works==>~^(.)\1{1,}$~

Thanks solarc. Your suggestion is good.

Comment: Where is your code? Show it please and also what went wrong and stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP preg_* functions the patterns has to have delimiters around. Ofter used is `~`, but it can be whatever.

```
~^(?!.*(.)\1).{*}$~
~^(.)\1{1,}$~
```

If you can work with the character which is used as a delimiter in your regex, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 4):

Why regex?

You could simply use

```
if ($mystring === str_repeat($mystring[0], strlen($mystring))) {
    // invalid
}
```